# Table not printing

Tags: tables

I'm having difficult time making the table code work for my paper.
The table code is

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular]{l l l}
\hline
v & a & b \\
4 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

in the preamable, I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, tabularx, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, setspace, graphicx, pdfpages, dcolumn, booktabs, url, float, relsize, fullpage, rotating, ccaption}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
```

I am really not sure why it's not working. Other tables work fine, but when I include this table, the texshop says that paragraph ended before `\begin` was complete.

I can't seem to really figure out what is really wrong with this code.

Answer (score 4):

Your code says `\begin{tabular]` instead of `\begin{tabular}` (compare the square bracket/brace at the end.)

Comment: I just found it. What a waste of time...Thank you anyway.